# What is the most efficient way to pass numpy array to c++ function and return numpy array as output?

Tags: python, c++, arrays, numpy

I've created a shared library. And I'm using it like that

```
class CAudioRecoveryStrategy(AbstractAudioRecoveryStrategy):
    def __init__(self):
        array_1d_double = npct.ndpointer(dtype=numpy.double, ndim=1, flags='CONTIGUOUS')
        self.lib = npct.load_library("libhello", ".")

        self.lib.demodulate.argtypes = [array_1d_double, array_1d_double, ctypes.c_int]

    def demodulate(self, input):
        output = numpy.empty_like(input)
        self.lib.demodulate(input, output, input.size)
        return output
```

Right now I have a problem, which is in c++ code I only have pointer to array of output data, not the array. So I can't return the array, unless I manually copy it.

What is the right way to do it? It must be efficient (like aligned memory etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Numpy arrays implement the buffer protocol, see 
https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/buffer.html.  In particular,
parse the input object to a PyObject* (conversion `O` if you're
using `PyArg_ParseTuple` or `PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords`), then
do `PyObject_CheckBuffer`, to ensure that the type supports the
protocol (numpy arrays do), then `PyObject_GetBuffer` to fill in
a `Py_buffer` struct with the physical addresses, dimensions,
etc. of the underlying memory block.  To return a numpy buffer
is more complicated; in general, I've found it sufficient to
create objects of my own type which also support the buffer
protocol (set `tp_as_buffer` to non null in the `PyTypeObject`).
Otherwise (but I've not actually tried this), you'll have to
import the numpy module, get its `array` attribute, call it with
the correct arguments, and then use the buffer protocol above on
the object you thus construct.

Comment: I'm not writing python extension. I'm using a shared library. So no PyObjects there.